# PHP insert row into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have already asked this but question was closed without answer so I post new question.
 I am trying to add values that are missing in second table
in table ps_psroduct supplier some values are missing and I want to add the from ps_product. So I want to list values that are missing and insert them in ps_product_supplier, there is no duplication.
Some values from ps_product are same in ps_product_supplier but not all so I want to filter thoese values and insert them correctly.
So some values exists in ps_product but not in ps_product_supplier and I want to insert missing rows in table by checking id_product and add missing.
What I have for now is that I get all the values printed  but I need only missing values that I can insert them in ps_product_supplier

How to do that?
In output I get:

```
USPJESNO ID 1 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 0
USPJESNO ID 2 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 1
USPJESNO ID 3 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 2
USPJESNO ID 4 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 3
USPJESNO ID 5 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 4
USPJESNO ID 6 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 5
```

for all the values, but I need to mach IDs and print only missing and create a row for it in ps_product_supplier with values from ps_product

```
$kveri = "SELECT id_product,id_supplier,supplier_reference, wholesale_price FROM ps_product";

    $ispis = mysql_query($kveri) or die(mysql_error());

               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ispis)){


               $trenutnired = $row['id_product'];
               $trenutnired1 = 0;
               $trenutnired2 = $row['id_supplier'];
               $trenutnired4 = $row['supplier_reference'];
               $trenutnired5 = $row['wholesale_price'];
               $trenutnired6 = 3;



                                                            //echo $trenutnired;

            //$drugatab = "SELECT * FROM ps_product_supplier WHERE id_product = '$trenutnired'";
            $drugatab = "SELECT id_product FROM ps_product_supplier WHERE id_product = '$trenutnired'";
            $rezultati = mysql_query($drugatab) or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($rezultati)){
            // Successful query...

            echo "USPJESNO ID $trenutnired ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: $countUpdated<br />";
            //mysql_query("INSERT INTO ps_product_supplier (id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier, product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency)  VALUES ('', '$trenutnired', '$trenutnired1',  '$trenutnired2', '$trenutnired4', '$trenutnired5', '$trenutnired6')");
            $countUpdated++;
        } else {
            //$countUpdated++;
            echo "ID $trenutnired ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: $countUpdated<br />";
        }
        }
```

This query works for one ID to insert data but I need for all that are missing:

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_supplier 
(id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier,
product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency)  
VALUES(NULL, 6216, 0, (SELECT id_supplier FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = 6216),
(SELECT supplier_reference FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = 6216), 
(SELECT wholesale_price FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = 6216), 3);
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I accept answers if they have connection to this, last case no answers that could help with this, so I ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to select products that *are* in ps_products, but are *not* in ps_productsuppliers.  If I'm right about that, this way is probably the easiest to understand.

```
select id_product
from ps_products
where id_product not in (select id_product from ps_product_supplier;
```

Comment: Yes just products that are not in ps_product_supplier
how can I do that